# Java: cannot access static variable from a different class in the same package

Tags: java, eclipse, static

This is quite odd, because I have a Character class that can access Frame.dimension.getWidth(); and its partner getHeight(), however when I wanted to use this in the Map class eclipse underlines it and cannot give me feedback. Running the program anyways ends up in java errors stating they can't find the X value of a Map object.

Here's the Frame class:

```
package Core;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Frame
{
static int width = 800, height = 600;
static Dimension dimension;

public static void main(String[]args){
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("RETRO");
    frame.add(new Screen());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width,height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    dimension = frame.getContentPane().getSize();
}
}
```

And the Map class:

```
package Core;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Map
{
    double x, y;

Image map;
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("images/Maps/maze.jpg");

public Map(){
    map = background.getImage();
}

public void move(double moveX, double moveY){
        x += moveX;
        y += moveY;
}

//////////Gets
public Image getMap(){
    return map;
}
public double getX(){
    if(x<0)
        x=0;
    else if(x>Frame.dimension.getWidth())
        x=Frame.dimension.getWidth();

    return x;
}

public double getY(){
    if(y<0)
        y=0;
    else if(y>Frame.dimension.getHeight())
        y=Frame.dimension.getHeight();

    return y;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return map.getHeight(null);
}

public int getWidth(){
    return map.getWidth(null);
}
}
```

I could provide the Character class but it is very long and messy at the moment.. however the word Frame was only used in the calling of Frame.dimension.getWidth()/getHeight();

Comment: btw, *really* bad idea to name one of your classes the same name as a `java.lang` class, namely `Character`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Frame class you refer to in `x=Frame.dimension.getWidth();` is `java.awt.Frame`. note that you imported this class. Try mentioning explicitly: `Core.Frame` instead or remove the line `import java.awt.Frame;` if you don't use this class.

Comment: >< Wows xD... I had a bunch of useless imports. Did not think they would mess it up. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

You may have a name clash with your own Core.Frame and Java's own java.awt.Frame.

I would re-name your Frame class to something different from a core-Java name, and I'd avoid using static variables as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Map` class is referring to `java.awt.Frame` (which you imported), not `Core.Frame`.

If you really need to keep the `import java.awt.Frame`, just use the fully qualified name of your frame class when referring to it (`Core.Frame`) to avoid the collision, e.g. in your `getX` method:

```
public double getX(){
    if(x<0)
        x=0;
    else if(x>Core.Frame.dimension.getWidth())
        x=Core.Frame.dimension.getWidth();

    return x; 
}
```

Or, if you don't really need to use `java.awt.Frame` at all, just remove that `import` line.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a collision between import between java.awt.Frame and Core.Frame

You should add "import static Core.Frame.dimension" to your imports, and then just work with "dimension" instead of "Frame.dimension"